# Java hashmap value to be used as a javascript hashmap in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, hashmap

I have a hashmap stored in request

```
request.setAttribute("occupationMap", occupationMap);
```

I need to store the same map in javascript hashmap on a JSP. So I can fetch the key values in multi-tier dropdown based on the conditions.

```
var occupationMap = '<%=request.getAttribute("occupationMap")%>';
alert(occupationMap);
```

Can anyone suggest how do I convert occupationMap into a javascript map on JSP.
Thanks.

Comment: you cant convert a java hashmap into a javascript map directly. you to convert it to json object first.

Comment: Well...I think you want your Java Hashmap to be part of your javascript code. So... when you are rendering jsp on server... all that html and javascript is just text... which means ... you need to convert your HashMap to string... And again... this string must be valid JSON. Which means you want to convert your HsahMap to a JSON string... which means you want to use one of `Gson` or `Jackson` or `org.json`.

Comment: Thanks people! I used Gson.

Answer (score 0):

/* JAVA changes*/
`Map<ABC,XYZ> map = new HashMap<>();`
`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();`
`String json = gson.toJson(map);`
`request.setAttribute("mapInjson",json);`
/*JSP changes*/
`String mapInString = request.getAttribute("mapInjson");`
`pageContext.set("mapInjson",mapInString);`
`var mapJs = "${mapInjson}";`
/*then you can access mapJs[KEY] to get the associated value*/